# Have different css rules for the same elements within different forms

Tags: html, css, forms

I currently have the two following forms.

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>First Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</form>
```

How can I have different rules for each form? The first one needs the contents centre aligned and the second needs the contents aligned left/padded left.

If I change the css for either the alignment and size change.

Thanks in advance.

*I've updated the form, how can I have it so that the text input is only styled for the left form? I don't want any text input rules on the center one.*

```css
.form-container {
background-color: #ff8e08;
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
}

.center-form {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.left-form {
text-align: left;
margin-left: 2vh;
}
input[type=text] {
width: 80%;
}
input[type="text"] {
padding: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="applicationform">
<br>

<form class="left-form">
<p>First Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<form class= "center-form">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you can add class to the form like <form class="some-class">....
and add styles to that class like text-align:center or left

Answer (score 2):

Add different class names for them.

CSS:

```
.center-form {
  /* center-form specific rules here */
}

.left-form {
 /* left-form specific rules here */
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="center-form">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<form class="left-form">
  <p>First Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</form>
```

And if you want to share some of the CSS rules that they both need:

```
.form {
    /* shared CSS rules */
}
```

Then, add this `form` class name to both of them in the HTML like this:

```
<form class="form center-form">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<form class="form left-form">
  <p>First Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</form>
```

Remeber, override class names like `center-form` and `left-form` should come after this `form`utility class name.

For your particular case, change your CSS to:

```
body {
  margin: 0; /* Remove user agent default styles */
}

.center-form {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-form {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 2vh;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 80%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit my answer directly. I've updated my answer. You can add `margin` in `.left-form`.  Is this what you want?

Comment: I've updated the form, how can I have it so that the text input is only styled for the left form? I don't want any text input rules on the center one. I've added this to the question @konekoya

Comment: You can do that like this `.left-form input[type="text"] {   /* your CSS rules here */ }`